# How can I match a string between two other known strings and nothing else with REGEX?

Tags: php, regex

I want to extract a string between two other strings. The strings happen to be within HTML tags but I would like to avoid a conversation about whether I should be parsing HTML with regex (I know I shouldn't and have solved the problem with stristr() but would like to know how to do it with regular expressions.

A string might look like this:

`...uld select &#8220;Apply&#8221; below.<br/><br/><b>Primary Location</b>: United States-Washington-Seattle<br/><b>Travel</b>: Yes, 75 % of the Time <br/><b>Job Type</b>: Standard<br/><b>Region</b>: US Service Lines: ASL - Business Intelligence<br/><b>Job</b>: Business Intelligence<br/><b>Capability Group</b>: Con/Sol - BI&C<br/><br/>LOC:USA`

I am interested in `<b>Primary Location</b>: United States-Washington-Seattle<br/>` and want to extract 'United States-Washington-Seattle'

I tried `'(?<=<b>Primary Location</b>:)(.*?)(?=<br/>)'` which worked in RegExr but not PHP:

`preg_match("/(?<=<b>Primary Location</b>:)(.*?)(?=<br/>)/", $description,$matches);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You used `/` as regex delimiter, so you need to escape it if you want to match it literally or use a different delimiter

```
 preg_match("/(?<=<b>Primary Location</b>:)(.*?)(?=<br/>)/", $description,$matches);
```

to

```
preg_match("/(?<=<b>Primary Location<\/b>:)(.*?)(?=<br\/>)/", $description,$matches);
```

or this

```
preg_match("~(?<=<b>Primary Location</b>:)(.*?)(?=<br/>)~", $description,$matches);
```

**Update**

I just tested it on www.writecodeonline.com/php and

```
$description = "uld select “Apply” below.<br/><br/><b>Primary Location</b>: United States-Washington-Seattle<br/><b>Travel</b>: Yes, 75 % of the Time <br/><b>Job Type</b>: Standard<br/><b>Region</b>: US Service Lines: ASL - Business Intelligence<br/><b>Job</b>: Business Intelligence<br/><b>Capability Group</b>: Con/Sol - BI&C<br/><br/>LOC:USA";
preg_match("~(?<=<b>Primary Location</b>:)(.*?)(?=<br/>)~", $description, $matches);

print_r($matches);
```

is working. Output:

> Array ( [0] => United States-Washington-Seattle [1] => United States-Washington-Seattle )

**You can also get rid of the capturing group and do**

```
$description = "uld select “Apply” below.<br/><br/><b>Primary Location</b>: United States-Washington-Seattle<br/><b>Travel</b>: Yes, 75 % of the Time <br/><b>Job Type</b>: Standard<br/><b>Region</b>: US Service Lines: ASL - Business Intelligence<br/><b>Job</b>: Business Intelligence<br/><b>Capability Group</b>: Con/Sol - BI&C<br/><br/>LOC:USA";
preg_match("~(?<=<b>Primary Location</b>:).*?(?=<br/>)~", $description, $matches);

print($matches[0]);
```

Output

> United States-Washington-Seattle

Comment: Thanks. That's a good point and will avoid an error but it still doesn't match anything.

Comment: Thanks. It isn;t working locally - probably for some other reason, though, so I'll accept the answer.

Comment: Turns out that simplepie was converting <br/> to <br> so that's why I was getting no matches. Grrrr